# TypeError: Swiper is not a constructor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, swiper.js

I'm trying to get Swiper to work but it always throw me an error "Swiper is not a constructor"

I'm using http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WMsuihJ96MI as the Swiper library and installed this library as a meteor package.

client/body.js

```
Template.slider.onRendered(function(){
     var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {

     // Optional parameters
     direction: 'vertical',
     loop: true,

     // If we need pagination
     pagination: '.swiper-pagination',

     // Navigation arrows
     nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
     prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',

     // And if we need scrollbar
     scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  });
});
```

client/body.html

```
<body>
   <h1>Test</h1>
 {{> slider }}
</body>

 <template name="slider">
   <!-- Slider main container -->
 <div class="swiper-container">
     <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
         <!-- Slides -->
         <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
     </div>
     <!-- If we need pagination -->
     <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

     <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
     <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

     <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
     <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Is this code in your imports folder?

Comment: I just tried your code in an empty project and it worked perfectly after adding the package. Check that you have nothing conflicting with the name Swiper, like another package. do 'console.log(Swiper)` and let us know what you get.

Comment: @jordanwillis Yes it is.

Comment: @mutdmour I got Object

Comment: Make sure you are importing it into your file.  If you got object on condole.log then thats a good thing

Comment: You should be getting a function for `Swiper` (an object for `new Swiper()`). What's the object? If you go into your browser console and enter `window.Swiper`, you should also get a function.

Comment: You could also try adding the file to your public folder and then importing as a script..

Answer (score 5):

@mutdmour You should try `Swiper.default(element,options)`

Make sure to console you Swiper instance and check if, It's really a constructor or it's an object which has it's constructor in it's property. Sorry if I give a wrong info. Because my english is very weak and this is my first reply to a Forum.

Comment: Constructor function must be called with "new": `new Swiper.default(element,options)`

Comment: on top of your answer, I tried require the package with:

const Swiper = require('Swiper').default;
then keep using new Swiper(element,options) instead of new Swiper.default(element,options), it also works.

Comment: @AlexanderMatveev thanks for this explanation as this worked for me for a slider called Splide which returned the same error Message. I use Vuejs the same way and don't get this error so this was very perplexing. I had to use default to get it to load past that error and use its initialization method called mount() which seems to work. I still have to update options and will update this further as I get it completed in case someone else using Splide happens by

Comment: How in the world do they NOT provide a simple example on how to initialize and then use the swiper? This is the first library that was a real pain to work with in 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i fixed it by changing
`import {Swiper, SwiperOptions} from "swiper";`
to
`import Swiper, {SwiperOptions} from "swiper"`;